# I migrated from webpack 4 to webpack 5 but my chunks are bigger than before

Tags: webpack

Everything went fine for the migration except the resulting bundle is heavier than before.

For an equivalent chunk, here is what I had before when comparing with webpack-bundle-analyzer :

```
117kb stat & 62kb parsed
https://pastebin.com/s2XUtYmd
```

With the latest version, I have this :

```
115kb stat & 156kb parsed
https://pastebin.com/KHUUP9PS
```

I've checked the two files and concluded that it may be because of the lack of full minimization with webpack 5 (some variables are minimized but not all).

Would you have an explanation to help me understand this problem ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I found it. devtool was set to 'eval' which prevented the compiler to remove dead code. No idea why but voilà !